# Return URL from PayPal not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal-sandbox

I have turned on the auto return url and set a return url address. But after successful transaction paypal is not redirecting to the return url. Anything else is required to make the redirection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possiblities

**1.if you testing payment from localhost it not work**

**2.You must have to enable auto return in your PayPal account, otherwise it will ignore the return field.**

you can enable using those steps ..

go to your PayPal merchant account-->profile-->Selling Preferences-->Website Payment Preferences-->Auto Return for Website Payments turn radio button to on,default it should off.

Documentation : https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/ipnguide.pdf

Comment: Thanks Anant, Do I need to set the return url in my code or else only enabling the return url will do the work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have turned on Auto Return and have chosen to turn on PayPal Account Optional for new users, a new user will not be automatically directed back to your website, but will be given the option to return.